# Angular2 router doesn't change component

Tags: angular, rxjs, subject-observer

I have 1 component that I want to reuse for different router links there routes look like:

```
{ path: '', component: OddComponent },
{ path: 'sport/:id', component: OddComponent },
{ path: 'sport/:id/category/:categoryid', component: OddComponent }
```

The component needs to fetch from different places with every router link. The problem is the component subscribes to a service and now every time I navigate to a different router link the subscriptions stack up. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `The problem is the component subscribes to a service` what does it mean ? bit more explanantion please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `onDestroy` hook to unsubscribe from the service before changing the route ...

[for more details](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#spy)